# OpenTelemetry Java Agent Warning - Multiple Values for Same Attributes in Scala Application

Tags: java, scala, open-telemetry

I'm currently using the OpenTelemetry Java agent in my Scala application and am encountering some issues.

The error I'm experiencing is as follows:

```
[otel.javaagent 2023-06-13 13:02:12:461 +0000] [PeriodicMetricReader-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.internal.state.AsynchronousMetricStorage - Instrument db.client.connections.usage has recorded multiple values for the same attributes.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. I've considered a few potential issues:

Concurrency: I do have multiple threads that might be recording measurements simultaneously, but I believed this was handled by the OpenTelemetry SDK.
Misuse of Instruments: I'm not certain if I'm using the right type of instrument for my use case, but db.client.connections.usage seems to be the best fit.

I'm also using version 1.25.1 of the OpenTelemetry Java agent SDK.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions on what might be causing this and how to fix it, I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: This might be an instrument being registered multiple times. Could it be that you should instantiate instruments statically in an `object` (possibly a companion) instead of a `class`?

Comment: @stefanobaghino I don't think so. According to the logs, it's related to "db.client.connections.usage" which I didn't manually instrument at all.

Comment: The db.client.connections.usage metric is emitted by the connection pool instrumentations in the javaagent. Are you using connection pools (e.g. Hikari) in your applications? Do you define more than one of them?

Comment: @MateuszRzeszutek Yes I use connection pools in order to connect to Mongo but there is just one.

Comment: I've checked the source code - but can't make out what could be causing the issue. I did create a PR to improve the log output, so hopefully you can re-test when the new version has been released: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/pull/5542

Comment: @GregorZeitlinger I'm still not able to understand why I get this. Is there any way to disable this instrumentation to avoid this log?

Comment: @oy121 yes, you can disable modules. First, check which modules are actually being used with https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#troubleshooting - look for something with jdbc or connection pool. Then, disable the instrumentation: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/#suppressing-specific-agent-instrumentation. It can take a bit of trial and error.